# Store Number to Decimal column

Tags: sql, oracle

I have one column in `table1 col1 NUMBER(13)`. I have to load the data from table1 to `table2 column col2 NUMBER(13,7)` and from table2 to `table3 column col3 NUMBER(13,5)`.
For example: 
`col1` has data as `0000049999999` than while storing it in `col2` it should be `4.9999999` and in `col3` it should be `5`.

I tried to convert the data using to_decimal but I am getting invalid identifier error.

Is there any other way to achieve this.

Comment: Show us your to_decimal attempt. (The one that fails.)

Comment: Are you sure that col1 is NUMBER(13)? "0000049999999" looks like a string

Comment: We will be getting the data in a file if we load it as NUMBER then the leading zeros will be excluded and the number in col1 will be stored as 49999999.

Comment: Even i tried to convert the number got in ctl to decimal by using ` col2 integer external (13) "to_number(:col2,'S99999d9999999')"`. But it did not worked

Comment: `SELECT CAST('0000049999999' AS DECIMAL(13,7)) FROM DUAL;` even this is also not working.

Comment: If a `to_decimal` function existed, what should it do? The [`DECIMAL`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/sqlqr/Data-Types.html#GUID-7FDD9381-7E1F-45FC-97FA-4CAFE1705350) type is just a subtype of `NUMBER` provided for ANSI compatibility, and you convert `49999999` to `4.9999999` by dividing by 1e7.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would expect these to work:

```
select cast(to_number('0000049999999') / 10000000 as decimal(13, 7)),
       cast(to_number('0000049999999') / 10000000 as decimal(13, 5))
from dual;
```

Oracle will not implicitly add a decimal point.  You can do so by division.